# Ayuda con vista en laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas noches amigos tengo un pequeño problema y no se como solucionarlo , el problema es el siguiente yo tengo una tabla que se llama transaccion la cual se encarga de registrar todas las transacciones que ocurren en mi aplicacion es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde por medio del campo transaccion_tipo_id me dice si es una compra o venta esa tabla es esta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

bueno hasta ahi todo bien  mi problema radica es en como hago para que una sola vista se encargue de registrar una transaccion sea el tipo que sea si no tengo un modelo de compra o de una venta y por lo tanto ningun controlador para mandarle informacion a esa vista, el objetivo de la tabla de transaccion es precisamente el de evitar tener tabla para cada tipo de transaccion.

Hasta el momento solo tengo creado el modelo de transacciones pero no tengo idea de como solucionar el problema propuesto gracias de antemano.

Comment: quize decir "modelo" de transacciones en ves de "borrador".

Comment: Sinceramente no termine de entender el problema.  ¿Por qué no creas un modelo para dicha tabla? Independientemente de que tengas un modelo o no puedes utilizar Query Builder para hacer consultas a dicha tabla en cualquier controlador.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes!

Por lo que he podido entender, quieres que con un sólo formulario se gestionen las diferentes transacciones.

Para ello podrías tener un select donde visualmente se verían las diferentes transacciones pero por detras se mandara la id de la transacción. Es decir :

```
 <select>
  <option value="1">Venta</option>
  <option value="2">Compra</option>
  <option value="3">Ingreso</option>
  <option value="4">Salida</option>
</select>
```

Comment: mm intentare aplicarlo gracias.